# MongoParseError: options poolsize, minsize are not supported in typeorm

Tags: typescript, connection, datasource, node.js-typeorm

```js
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm'

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  "type": "mongodb",
  "url": process.env.DB_URL,
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  minSize:8,
  poolSize:10,
  maxQueryExecutionTime: 30000,
  useNewUrlParser:true,
  entities: [Admin, Store],
  migrations: [
    PopulateReportTypes1231649246273594,
    CreateEtest1689344781759578,
  ],
  subscribers: []
})
```

Basically, I want to use poolsize, so that I can handle connection with MongoDB.
I am facing quotes problem with MongoDB. Multiple connection are added at once.

For this reason the server is down.

please help me how I can use poolsize.so that I can set the maximum request connection